# C#/LINQ to SQL - order combined results from two different result sets

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, concatenation

The sad part is, I've done this before.  I remember figuring this out.  Today, I can't seem to recall how to do this.

So you have this list:

```
public List<taters> getTaters(){
    var firstTaters = from s in n.veggies
                      where s.active == true
                     select s.html;

    var secondTaters = from s in n.roots
                      where s.active == true
                     select s.html;

    //now here I want to do something to combine the two 
    //(e.g. a Concat or some such) and   
    //THEN I want to order the concatenated list of results 
    //by 'date_created' descending.  
}
```

Question in above comments.  How do I order them AFTER joining them together?

Comment: `firstTaters.Concat(secondTaters).OrderBy(d => d.date_created)` .....?

Comment: Yeah, I can concatenate (join the two results into one list of results like this  firstTaters.Concat(secondTaters)

But then...I want to order them by 'date_created' which they both have as fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
firstTaters.Concat(secondTaters)
           .OrderByDescending(html => html.date_created)
```

also try to use concatenation on two sets before filtering, to avoid code duplication (may be slower, but is more maintainable)

```
public IEnumerable<taters> getTaters()
{
    return from s in n.veggies.Concat(n.roots)
           where s.active == true
           orderby s.html.date_created descending
           select s.html;
}
```

Don't forget to call `ToList` or change signature to return `IQueryble<taters>` or `IEnumerable<taters>`

Comment: Woah - yeah!  Lamda statements!!!!  Forgot somehow.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Concat`, or use `Union` if you want distinct results

```
var concated = 
    firstTaters.Concat(secondTaters).OrderByDescending(html => html.date_created);

//Gives distinct values
var unioned = 
    firstTaters.Union(secondTaters).OrderByDescending(html => html.date_created);
```

Comment: Excellent point on the Union.  Definitely good if there's any need for distincts.  Thanks.  Lambda Expression fits the bill nicely - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do this like in the bellow example:

```
public List<taters> getTaters(){
    var firstTaters = from s in n.veggies
                      where s.active == true
                     select s.html;

    var secondTaters = from s in n.roots
                      where s.active == true
                     select s.html;

    return (
        from first in firstTaters
        join second in secondTaters on secondTaters.someField equals second.someField
        select new 
        {
            ....
            ....
        }
    ).toList();
}
```

Comment: I wonder whether this or the Lambda expressions make for a faster/more efficient choice....

Comment: I forget to put the order by clause before the to list statement. I like this way because I can create different object tipes. Of course you can also create you taters object in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this :

```
return firstTaters.Concat(secondTaters).OrderByDescending(el => el.DateCreated);
```